# cocoa - App architecture

Tags: xcode, json, cocoa, http, architecture

I've a app that lives of making HTTP GET calls, and parsing the JSON responses. I've about 5/6 different views, where that are waiting for that responses to present the information. The contents are much like text and images.

Problems:
- If I make the requests only when the user enters on the view, he have to wait to much, and that's not a good user experience.
- If I make all the requests on the first viewcontroller, the app becomes more slow, and sometimes it takes to long to respond to the user taps.

Questions:
- What is the best way to implement the app, so I've a good user experience and a good performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends on the amount of data you ae downloading. If a view needs a lot of data it might be best to download it only when this view is about to be shown, so your app doesn't unnecessarily use bandwidth.

If you do want to load the data up front it might be best to do so in a separate thread so the UI thread isn't blocked.

You could also cache the data and use this cache while the newest data is downloading in the background. This creates a seamless user experience.